# PHP BUG, uploading images

Tags: php

so working on an assignment for school. stuck on question, i have no idea how to fix this or where to look (they don't provide much help either).

heres the question.

There is a bug on the "editBanner.php" page. When you delete an image, that number is deleted. When a new file is uploaded, it is given the number of one more than the total of current banners. There is a major problem with this, e.g. if we have four banners: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we delete 2.jpg, we are left with 1.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we then uploaded a new image, the page would count the number of images (in this case three) and add 1, giving us a new file name of "4.jpg". We already have a file called 4.jpg, therefore, the old 4.jpg would be replaced. Find a way to fix this error so the images are never replaced.

here's the code. any help would be fantastic. and thanks in advance. and if you know a fix, if you could explain the fix and how it works, that would be awesome.

```
<?php 
require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php"); 
require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");
include("Includes/header.php");        

          confirm_is_admin();   

        $dir = 'Images/banner';
          $confirmation = "";

          if(isset($_GET["del"])){
            if (file_exists($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"])) {
                unlink($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"]);
                $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " deleted. <br><br>";
            } else {
                $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " doesn't exist. <br><br>";
          }
          }

          $files = scandir($dir);
          array_shift($files);
          array_shift($files);

          $newImage = COUNT($files)+1;

          if(isset($_GET["add"])) {
               $confirmation = "Image successfully uploaded.";
          }

          if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);

            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50 * 1024 * 1024) //50mb (1024 * 1kb = 1mb, 50 x 1024kb = 50mb)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
              } else {
                    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . "kB<br>";
                    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir ."/" . $newImage . "." . $extension);
                    echo "Stored in: " . $dir . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    header("Location: editBanner.php?add=1");
              }
            } else {
              echo "Invalid file";
              }
            }
?>

<div id="container">
        <div id="admin">
            <?php
                if(!empty($confirmation)) {
                    echo "<div id='confirmation'>" . $confirmation . "</div>";
                }

                for ($i = 0; $i < COUNT($files); $i++) {
                    echo '<div id="bannerImage">';
                    echo $files[$i] . ' - <a href="editBanner.php?del=' . $files[$i] . '">Delete</a><br>';
                    echo '<img src="' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '"width="200px" height="100px" /><br>';
                    echo '</div>';
          $files[$i--];
                }
            ?>

      <style>
        #bannerAdd {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 700px;  
        } 
      </style>

      <div id="bannerAdd" >
      <form action="editBanner.php" method="post"     
          enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <h3>Upload a New Banner Image</h3>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div> <!-- End of outer-wrapper which opens in header.php -->
<?php 
  include ("Includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but are those your homework?

Comment: yeah my first in php studies. it's a nightmare.

Comment: `$newImage = COUNT($files)+1;` - that is the line where you construct your new file name. It has been pointed out that it causes a major problem in the given situation. Change it to something that is unique at least in the list of image names you have.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the names based on date and time.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newImage = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
```

This way you'll not have problem with your filename, and it will be unique names too.